# How to fix temporal table history removal?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

For my project I need to interact with historical table and delete repeating  rows from it:

```
Id  Name   SysStartTime SysEndTime
-----------------------------------
123 FooBar 2015-11-15   2015-11-16
123 FooBar 2015-11-16   2015-11-17
123 FooBar 2015-11-17   2015-11-18
```

But, obviously, any deletion will break history intervals `SysStartTime`, `SysEndTime`:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
    SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)

DELETE FROM [dbo].[MyTableHistory] 
WHERE SysStartTime = '2020-11-16'

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
    SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[MyTableHistory]))
```

And gap will occur:

```
123 FooBar 2015-11-15 2015-11-16
--> deleted, but gap between 2015-11-16 and 2015-11-17 is not imprinted in any of those upper/lower revisions
123 FooBar 2015-11-17 2015-11-18
```

So this will affect all historical queries in which you need to find entities on this date.

Is there any built-in method rather than writing some ugly SQL to fix this? Preferably, it should be previous one revision, but any will do actually.

Comment: So what would you want to do, change the `SysEndTime` values of the previous record to the next available `SysStartTime`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did the data get like this? I know that Temporal Tables has the ability to let you specify your own table that holds the history (along with data). I assume that's what happened here.

Comment: Actually, there is other fields, but they are of no importance, for example: Id,Name,UnimportantData. So despite it was used sometime ago, it disappeared after migration on new schema - and intervals stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to delete a row (or rows) from the history table, and change the previous rows to covert it up - effectively deleting a change from history.
Here's a T-SQL script that will do that for you - delete all changes from a specific date.

```sql
DECLARE @DeletedDates AS TABLE
(
    DateFrom DateTime2(7),
    DateTo DateTime2(7)
);

BEGIN TRANSACTION; -- I'm assuming this is an atomic operation...
BEGIN TRY

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF )

DELETE 
FROM [dbo].[MyTableHistory] 
OUTPUT deleted.SysStartTime, deleted.SysEndTime INTO @DeletedDates
WHERE SysStartTime >= '2020-11-16T00:00:00' 
AND SysStartTime < '2020-11-17T00:00:00'
-- Note: SysStartTime and SysEndTime are datetime2(7). 
-- I'm assuming you want to delete changes in a specific date.

UPDATE t
SET SysEndTime = DateTo
FROM [dbo].[MyTableHistory] AS t
JOIN @DeletedDates AS DeletedDates
ON t.SysEndTime = DeletedDates.DateFrom;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[MyTableHistory]));

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW; 
END CATCH
```